# Get DataTable from DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have one form that is a CRUD, this form can manage any data from many tables, if a table has foreign keys the CRUD found the tables and columns for respectives columns of the current table, so in the DataGridView can show columns as CheckBox, TextBox or ComboBox

I do all this BEFORE the DataGridView is filled with the data, so I can't use this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtCurrent;
```

I need something like this:

```
dtCurrent = dataGridView1.DataSource;
```

But just give a null

I have tried with **ExtensionMethod** to the DataGridView:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this DataGridView dataGridView, string tableName)
{

    DataGridView dgv = dataGridView;
    DataTable table = new DataTable(tableName);

    // Crea las columnas 
    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < dgv.Columns.Count; iCol++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(dgv.Columns[iCol].Name);
    }

    /**
      * THIS DOES NOT WORK
      */
    // Agrega las filas 
    /*for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        // Obtiene el DataBound de la fila y copia los valores de la fila 
        DataRowView boundRow = (DataRowView)dgv.Rows[i].DataBoundItem;
        var cells = new object[boundRow.Row.ItemArray.Length];
        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < boundRow.Row.ItemArray.Length; iCol++)
        {
            cells[iCol] = boundRow.Row.ItemArray[iCol];
        }

        // Agrega la fila clonada                 
        table.Rows.Add(cells);
    }*/

    /* THIS WORKS BUT... */
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {

        DataRow datarw = table.NewRow();

        for (int iCol = 0; iCol < dgv.Columns.Count; iCol++)
        {
            datarw[iCol] = row.Cells[iCol].Value;
        }

        table.Rows.Add(datarw);
    }

    return table;
}
```

I use:

```
dtCurrent = dataGridView1.ToDataTable(dtCurrent.TableName);
```

The code does not works when:

```
int affectedUpdates = dAdapter.Update(dtCurrent);
```

I get an Exception about duplicated values (translated from spanish):

**The changes requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.**

I just need to Update changes in the DataGridView using DataTable

Answer (score 8):

alternatively this may help toconvert datagrigview to datatable.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt = (DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable))
```

do a direct casting on datagridview for datatable can get the final result.

Comment: Similar to the above `DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) dataGridView1.DataSource;` worked for me.
See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295161/how-to-build-a-datatable-from-a-datagridview

Comment: In C#, var dt = new DataTable(); dt = (DataTable)DataGridView1.DataSource;

Comment: This solution gave me error "unable to cast object of type Dataview to type DataTable".

Answer (score 8):

If you need a reference to the actual DataTable source, try this

```
 ((DataRowView)DataGridView1.Rows[0].DataBoundItem).DataView.Table
```

don't forget to process errors.

Comment: ((DataRowView)DataGridView1.Rows[0].DataBoundItem).DataView has the values i previously put.
but ((DataRowView)DataGridView1.Rows[0].DataBoundItem).DataView.Table contains no value.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote something like this:

```
private DataTable GetDataGridViewAsDataTable(DataGridView _DataGridView) 
{
    try {
        if (_DataGridView.ColumnCount == 0) return null;
        DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
        //////create columns
        foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in _DataGridView.Columns) {
            if (col.ValueType == null) dtSource.Columns.Add(col.Name, typeof(string));
            else dtSource.Columns.Add(col.Name, col.ValueType);
            dtSource.Columns[col.Name].Caption = col.HeaderText;
        }
        ///////insert row data
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in _DataGridView.Rows) {
            DataRow drNewRow = dtSource.NewRow();
            foreach(DataColumn col in dtSource.Columns) {
                drNewRow[col.ColumnName] = row.Cells[col.ColumnName].Value;
            }
            dtSource.Rows.Add(drNewRow);
        }
        return dtSource;
    }
    catch {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ((DataTable)DataGridView1.DataSource);
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score -2):

What about this :

```
DataView dv = (DataView)(dataGridView1.DataSource);

dt = dv.ToTable();
```

Works for all case!

Comment: You can't convert DataTable to DataView. Just use DataTable dt = (DataTable)(dataGridView1.DataSource); directly, no conversion to DataView needed.