# How to build a DataTable from a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I may well be looking at this problem backwards but I am curious none the less.  Is there a way to build a `DataTable` from what is currently displayed in the `DataGridView`?

To be clear, I know you can do this `DataTable data = (DataTable)(dgvMyMembers.DataSource);` however that includes hidden columns.  I would like to build it from the displayed columns only.

Hope that makes sense.

---

So I ended up trying a combination of a couple of answers as that seemed best.  Below is what I am trying.  Basically I am creating the DataTable from the DataSource and then working backwards based on if a column is visible or not.  However, after it removes a column I get a `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` on the next iteration of the `foreach`.

I am confused as I am not ***trying*** to modify the `DataGridView`, only the `DataTable` so what's up?

```
DataTable data = GetDataTableFromDGV(dgvMyMembers);


    private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var dt = ((DataTable)dgv.DataSource).Copy();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if (!column.Visible)
            {
                dt.Columns.Remove(column.Name);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: You're getting the error because the DataTable is bound to the DGV; when you remove the column from the DT, the bound column from the DGV is also removed.  Make a copy of the DT before removing columns,  Change your assignment to `dt` to:  `var dt = ((DataTable)dgv.DataSource).Copy();`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, you can do

```
DataTable data = (DataTable)(dgvMyMembers.DataSource);
```

and then use

```
data.Columns.Remove(...);
```

I think it's the fastest way. This will modify data source table, if you don't want it, then copy of table is reqired. Also be aware that `DataGridView.DataSource` is not necessarily of `DataTable` type.

Comment: Nice answer!  I appreciate concise code.  I also give you credit for using Gadget as your avatar.  Old-school for the win!

Comment: I am not sure who to give the checkmark to on this.  My solution ended up being an equal combination of this answer and Jay Riggs answer.

Comment: This works only if datasource is not null

Answer (score 16):

I don't know anything provided by the Framework (beyond what you want to avoid) that would do what you want but (as I suspect you know) it would be pretty easy to create something simple yourself:

```
private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv) {
    var dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns) {
        if (column.Visible) {
            // You could potentially name the column based on the DGV column name (beware of dupes)
            // or assign a type based on the data type of the data bound to this DGV column.
            dt.Columns.Add();
        }
    }

    object[] cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++) {
            cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

one of best solution enjoyed it ;)

```
  public DataTable GetContentAsDataTable(bool IgnoreHideColumns=false)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dgv.ColumnCount == 0) return null;
                DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
                {
                    if (IgnoreHideColumns & !col.Visible) continue;
                    if (col.Name == string.Empty) continue;
                    dtSource.Columns.Add(col.Name, col.ValueType);
                    dtSource.Columns[col.Name].Caption = col.HeaderText;
                }
                if (dtSource.Columns.Count == 0) return null;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow drNewRow = dtSource.NewRow();
                    foreach (DataColumn  col in dtSource .Columns)
                    {
                        drNewRow[col.ColumnName] = row.Cells[col.ColumnName].Value;
                    }
                    dtSource.Rows.Add(drNewRow);
                }
                return dtSource;
            }
            catch { return null; }
        }
```

Comment: The exeption occurs in  dtSource.Columns.Add(col.Name, col.ValueType); command if ValueType == null

Answer (score 3):

First convert you datagridview's data to List, then convert List to DataTable

```
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>( this List<T> list) where T : class {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var ps = type.GetProperties ( );
        var cols = from p in ps
                   select new DataColumn ( p.Name , p.PropertyType );

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(cols.ToArray());

        list.ForEach ( (l) => {
            List<object> objs = new List<object>();
            objs.AddRange ( ps.Select ( p => p.GetValue ( l , null ) ) );
            dt.Rows.Add ( objs.ToArray ( ) );
        } );

        return dt;
    }
```