# Copying all rows from one DataGrid to another

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to copy all the selected rows from one datagrid to another. Here is what i've been trying to do so far:

```
private void btnFeedbackSelectSupplier_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dgFeedbackAddCost.SelectAll();

    IList list = dgFeedbackAddCost.SelectedItems as IList;
    IEnumerable<ViewQuoteItemList> items = list.Cast<ViewQuoteItemList>();

    //Example of how I want to access the data from the first datagrid and add it to
    //the second one.
    var item = (new ViewQuoteItemList
    {
        Item = items.Item,
        Supplier = items.Cost
    });
    //Example

    dgFeedbackSelectSupplier.Items.Add(item);
}
```

My issue is here:

```
var item = (new ViewQuoteItemList
{
    Item = items.Item,
    Supplier = items.Cost
});
```

And I'm getting the error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method
>   'Item' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Now I know I'm doing it wrong, it's just I don't know how else I can show you what I want to achieve with the code snippets.

So my question is, how would I be able to access that data from the `items` cast and add it to my `ViewQuoteItemList` for my second datagrid?

Comment: What you want is the element in the `items` (rather than the `items.Item` something like `items[0].Item`, I mean?) isn't it? How do you want to exactly get the `item`? from `items[0]`? `items[1]`? `items[2]`? each `item` in `items`?

Comment: why not save the first datagridview to a datatable, then reimport that table as the source for the second data gridview?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ian. Yes I want to get each item in Items. Foreach statement maybe?

Comment: Hi Takarri! And thanks for the comment. Do you have any examples of how I could do that?

Comment: Just to get every item, you could use LINQ. But to assign every item: you could actually do it in the LINQ as well, but normally it is not advised to make such addition of item in together with the query, so in my answer, I split them. To add the item I use `foreach` but for the query, you could use LINQ. You might also consider to use `DataGridViewRow` object (in the `foreach`) to pass on your data nicely one row by one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all the new items using LINQ:

```
var items2 = (from i in items
           let a = new ViewQuoteItemList { Item = i.Item, Supplier = i.Cost }
           select a).ToList();

foreach(var item in items2)
    dgFeedbackSelectSupplier.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: @CareTaker22 glad to know that! ;) hope that it may be helpful in your learning about LINQ too..

Comment: Hi Ian. Me again. Seeing as you helped me with this problem of mine and is good in C#. I was wondering if you might have the time to look at another question I made a while ago. No one has answered or commented on my question so far and I am in dire need of help. The [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138374/adding-data-only-to-a-specific-column-in-a-datagrid) to my question if you want to view it. I really hope you can help or just give me a small tip :)

Comment: @CareTaker22 Seems like we live in different timezone here... Ok, I will go and check.

Answer (score 1):

This would satisfy your need to only add the selected rows to the datatable. Then you can merge 2 datatables if you just want to add them together - then rebind the source to the second grid.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    dt.Columns.Add(column.Name, column.CellType);
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
{
     dt.Rows.Add();
     for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
         dt.Rows[i][j] = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value;

     }
 }
```

Reference [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295161/how-to-build-a-datatable-from-a-datagridview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Takarii! :) Ian's answer was simpler and got the job done for now. Thank you for the effort man. I will keep your answer for later issues if I run into any ;)