# Dynamic DataGridView Filtering c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, linq-to-sql

I just started to work on c# and sql, I searched but I couldn't find any solution to my problem I hope someone will help me.
I have a `DataGridView` on the form which is created by dynamically. I get 8 columns from database using LINQ to SQL. but I also create another column name as a "Calculation" which is using the other columns data. My question is I need to filter my table based on calculation column. Below part of my code:

```
// get datas from database.
var query = _context.Database.SqlQuery<my_Type>("my_stored_procedure");

var binding = new BindingList<my_Type>(query.ToList());
            bsMasterPrimary.DataSource = binding;
            myDataGridView.DataSource = bsMasterPrimary;


//filter

DataView dv = new DataView();

dv = myDataGridView.DataSource as DataView;//dv always comes null 



dv.RowFilter = string.format("Calculation <0");
  //  dt = (DataTable)((BindingSource)this.dgvAmazonFBAInventory.DataSource).DataSource;
```

I tried this too but it gave an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1[MyProject.MyType]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.
>   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to use a nested for loop to assign the values of the data grid view to the datatable
OR
you can cast the datagrid into a dataview then convert the data view to a datatable

Comment: I tried to cast my DataGridView to DataView but I failed couple times.How can I do this?I tried
DataView dv = MyDataGridView.DataSource as DataView But it didn't work thank you.

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295161/how-to-build-a-datatable-from-a-datagridview

Comment: Basically DataTable dt =(DataTable) datagridview.datasource

Comment: Thank you.But now I am getting this error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'MyProject.usp_MyDataType'. How  can I convert DataViewRow to spesific datatype. ? thnak you

Comment: You can try casting to your defied type or use loops to add each element to the new type

Comment: my problem is when I cast my DataTable from DatagridView the column that I added dynamically always comes with null value and I need to sort my table based on that column.Basically DataGridView isn't a table?So why I cant reach the column that I added with the code?

Comment: If you are using loops then this should read all the data from the view. use the itterations from each loop as the indexes of the datagrid view and get the value of each cell

Comment: foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in myDataGridView.Columns) {
                 DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
                 dc.ColumnName = c.Name;
                 dc.DataType = c.ValueType;
                 dt.Columns.Add(dc);}
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in MyGridView.Rows) {
                 DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
                 foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in r.Cells) {
                     drow[cell.OwningColumn.Name] = cell.Value; }
                dt.Rows.Add(drow); }
I read GridView and create datatable like this.Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For ( int a =0; a <dgv.rows.count; a++){datatable.rows [a][column name]= dgv.rows [a].cells [column name].value;}   this will fill one column.  Repeat for all columns